# Haskell folding nested lists

Tags: haskell

Currently I'm messing around with Haskell. My knowledge about Haskell (and functional languages in general) is still low but I'm working on it.
What really bothers me is a (as I thought) simple task: folding nested lists with one fold per depth.

```
fcalc = foldr (\x y -> (foldr (**) 1 x) * (foldr (**) 1 y)) [1.0, 1.0] [[2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0]]
```

What it should do: 2^3 * 4^5 where the ^ is done by the lambda'd inner folds. Sadly it does not work.

```
Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: t0 = [t0]
In the third argument of `foldr', namely `y'
```

I've read a bit about the given "infinite type" error mainly indicating that a variable is used as e.g. element while it was a list instead. This made me thinking about the second param of the outer foldr as the problem but without success.
I just don't get it. :/

Comment: Well, I wonder if you aren't going the wrong way about this.  First of all, you're breaking one of my rules of thumb: you don't use folds to solve a problem directly, you use them to implement some intermediate abstraction to solve your problem.  Second, I wonder if lists and nested lists are really the correct data structure for what you're trying to do; I get the feeling that you're dealing with a problem area better served by some sort of abstract syntax tree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that you're trying to do the `a^b` calculation on your accumulator inside the fold, while also doing it on each element. What you really want is something like

```
fcalc = foldr (\x y -> (foldr (**) 1 x) * y) 1 [[1.0, 1.0], [2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0]]
```

Remember, the output of each step of `foldr` is plugged in as the second argument of the next step (e.g. the `y` variable in this case). Since your `foldr` step is returning a number, the `y` variable is already a number, and therefore you can't fold over it.

Comment: Oh dear, how could I think in such a wrong way... thanks a lot for correcting my understanding of folds.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer to your question, but an alternative way to solve your problem:

```
haskell> sum $ map ((**) <$> (!! 0) <*> (!! 1)) xs
1032.0
```

Or, if you are not comfortable with pointfree:

```
haskell> sum $ map (\x -> let (a:b:_) = x in a ** b) xs
1032.0
```

Comment: If you want to encode the fact that you're only looking at the first two elements, you may as well switch over to using tuples instead.

Comment: Sure, but only if you know at the compile time that it's going to be a tuple.